# ¿Cómo repetir una función?

Tags: python, while, function, pygame

Estoy practicando python con un juego sencillo de space invaders. Ya casi lo estoy terminando, y en esta parte de código, donde estoy creando el "game over", no consigo regresar a la función juego "def juego". Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias de antemano.

```
##bucle principal
while jugando:
    if rstart is False:
        letra30 = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 100)
        mensaje_bienvenida = letra30.render("Bienvenidos!!", 1, (white))
        ventana.blit(mensaje_bienvenida, (150, 300))
        pygame.display.flip()  ##funcion para actualizar pantalla y que se pueda ver mensaje de bienvenida
        for event in pygame.event.get():  ##menu principal
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    juego()  ##sentencia para que se ejecute "def juego" y comience el juego
    if rstart is True:
        letra1 = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 100)
        mensaje_final = letra1.render("Game Over!!", 1, (white))
        ventana.blit(mensaje_final, (200, 300))
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():  ##funcion para que reaccione al presionar una tecla
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    pygame.display.update()
                    juego()

    def juego():
        global rstart
        while juego:
            global contador
            global laser_state
            global laser_y
            clock.tick(FPS)
            contador += 1 / 120
            ventana.fill((0, 0, 0))
            ventana.blit(BG, (0, 0))
            jugador()
            ##aparicion de enemigos
            creacion_enemigos()

            teclado()
            etiquetas()

            ##movimiento laser
            if laser_state is "fire":
                fuego_laser(laser_x, laser_y)
                laser_y -= lasery_change

                if laser_y <= 0:
                    laser_state = "ready"

            if lives == 0:
                rstart = True
                return

            pygame.display.update() ##funcion para actualizar la pantalla
```

Buenas comunidad! Estoy practicando python con un juego sencillo de space invaders. Ya casi lo estoy terminando, y en esta parte de código, donde estoy creando el "game over", no consigo regresar a la función juego "def juego". Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tienes una función definida al interior de un `while` ... mejor la mueves fuera y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no consigo regresar" ... ?

Comment: coloque finalmente def fuera del while, y funciona. Además, agregué algún retoque. Se trataba de hacer una especie de menú de opciones, cuando acabara el juego "game over", que el jugador tenga la posibilidad de hacer un reset. Conseguido...Gracias por el aporte"